# How can I lock a record across multiple instance of a program using hibernate and postrgresql?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, postgresql-9.2

I would like to find a way to lock a record from instance A making so that instance B can *know* that the record is locked.

Here is how the GUI is working :

On instance A the user ask for modification of entity E. The program *check* something (try to reserve a token ? something else ? ...) and show a *modification dialog* if E is free.

Lets say that instance A was able to *reserve* E, and instance B wants to open the same window. B try to lock the record (with yet to be found solution) and because A is already there, B is only displaying *consultation* dialog.

I am using :

- java
- hibernate on each instance
- postgresql (maybe there is a lock behavior I can use ?)

Note : I only want to lock 1 record of a table, not the entire table.

Can someone give me a hint on what to use and maybe tell me also how I can manage an unlock protection if instance A crash ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seeing if it's free and locking has to be the same step. Otherwise, someone else might get it after you've checked.

Comment: I think that something like *reserve the token* might be a good solution, with error when it is already taken. The *free and locking* could be already coded on the database side ?

Comment: Have a look at advisory locks: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that what you want is a `select for update`. This will lock the row preventing your other transactions from writing or getting a write lock on it. The question is, what happen when another transaction try a `select for update` too. I'm not sure if it will block or trow an exception right away. You should try it.

Hibernate: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html section 11.4
Postgress: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html

With this solution, you do not have to worry about stale lock since if you app crash, the transaction will close and the lock will be released. If the DBMS does not realize that the client is gone fast enough, you could always kill that transaction directly on the database.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, and what I finally manage to find / use. `getSession().buildLockRequest(new LockOptions(LockMode.UPGRADE_NOWAIT)).lock(entity)` lock for instance A, throw an PessimisticLockException exception for instance B.